# UILocalNotification when the application is active?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

If my App receives a `UILocalNotification` when it is active, I want to show my own `UIAlertView` and dismiss the system alert. Here's what I'm doing:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = ... 
        [alert show];
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

My own alert shows up, but the system alert somehow remains in the system and is shown as soon as I exit my App.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may have a look below link;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555564/is-it-possible-to-pop-up-local-notifications-while-the-iphone-app-is-on-screen

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `[[UIApplication shareApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];` 
set it as `[notification setFireDate:nil];`.