# Is it possible to pop up local notifications while the iphone app is on screen?

Tags: iphone, notifications

I need a local notification for an iphone app to pop up while the app is active. Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: To get notification your application should be in background.

Comment: Just to show that this should be possible, unless Apple doesn't let others do this, an example of when this happens is in the Messages app from Apple.  If you are chatting with someone, and you get a text from someone else, you still get a notification, whether local or push.  When you touch it, it will go to a chatview with that person.

Answer (score 13):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

is called if you have a notification scheduled and the app is already running..it is a `UIApplication` delegate method..

here you can do your custom code..by accessing the notification...

**edit :**

if you want to present a notification right now .. then you can just set the notification fire date to past...it will be fired..then you can create a alert view in the above given UIapplication method

Comment: but how do you still force the notification to SHOW, if it's received in the didReceiveLocalNotification function?

Comment: @mix3d sadly not possible. Apple designed it so that Local notifications don't show if the app is on the foreground.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a same animation in app.

I made a lib to make an animation almost as same as local notification's.

Check this:
https://github.com/OpenFibers/OTNotification

Demo:
[image]

[image]

And you can post a new message to this lib when you received a message in

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:    (UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    OTNotificationManager *notificationManager = [OTNotificationManager defaultManager];
    OTNotificationMessage *notificationMessage = [[OTNotificationMessage alloc] init];
    notificationMessage.title = [self notificationTitle];
    notificationMessage.message = @"A notification. Touch me to hide me.";
    [notificationManager postNotificationMessage:notificationMessage];
}
```

Comment: Hey this looks quite nice, any chance you are going to update it for ios 7 and 8?

Answer (score 3):

Local notifications and push notifications are ways for an application that isn’t running in the foreground to let its users know it has information for them. The information could be a message, an impending calendar event, or new data on a remote server. When presented by the operating system, local and push notifications look and sound the same. They can display an alert message or they can badge the application icon. They can also play a sound when the alert or badge number is shown.For detail knowledge see this link [Local Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: *Local notifications and push notifications are ways for an application that isn’t running in the foreground to let its users know it has information for them.* this was very valuable information for me. I have been struggling with this for hours today but now I know I shouldn't even be trying to use UILocalNotification for my situation (presenting a notification to user when something happens). Can give that up and look for a better solution :-)