# Local notification alert sound not playing on iPad but same playing for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uilocalnotification

i am playing custom sound for local notification.

```
  notification.soundName=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundName" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

I am setting custom sound for local notification. When notification fire sound is playing in iPhone(IOS 7) but not playing in iPad(IOS 6.1.3).
Please tell me what is wrong with code for iPad.

**Note- Setting-> sound-> ringer and alerts for both device sound is zero. But it plays well in iPhone but not in iPad**

Is it necessary to set alert sound for notification sound?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16030356/2265218 check this link..

Comment: (If you check it in device the )May be It is funny but first check your iPad volume level is proper or not ?? because it work on iPhone then it should be work in iPad also.

Comment: Hi ipatel i check device sound Setting-> sound-> ringer and alerts for both my sound is zero. But it plays well in iPhone but not in iPad :(

Comment: @krish - okay try with full path of sound name such like `localNotif.soundName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundName" ofType:@"mp3"];`

Comment: @iPatel yes i am using full path. The only difference is that iPhone have iOS 7 but in iPad IOS 6.1.3

Comment: check sound is un muted ..

Answer (score 0):

try changing your files extension from mp3 to .aiff files